# ko observable array not triggering when last element removed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a map with an element that shows which layers are currently loading. I hold a list of the layer names in a knockout observable array. When new layers are being loaded they show as expected. When layers finish loading they are removed as expected, except for the last one. This isn't removed even though debugging shows the list it is bound to is now empty.

To initialise the observable:

```
self.currentlyLoadingLayers = ko.observableArray([]);
```

when about to load the layer:

```
self.layerLoadingStarted(layerName);
```

event that gets fired when layer has loaded:

```
layer.events.register('loadend', layer, function () {
    self.layerLoadingFinished(layerName);
});
```

and the functions that get called:

```
self.layerLoadingStarted = function (layerName) {
    self.currentlyLoadingLayers.push(layerName);
};

self.layerLoadingFinished = function(layerName) {
    for (var i = self.currentlyLoadingLayers().length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (self.currentlyLoadingLayers()[i] === layerName) {
            self.currentlyLoadingLayers().splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    //if (self.currentlyLoadingLayers().length === 0) self.currentlyLoadingLayers([]);
};
```

if I uncomment the final line in the function above then everything works. Why is this required? Shouldn't the fact that the array is now empty be observed automatically?

My bindings:

```
<div id="layersLoadingMessage" data-bind="visible: $root.currentlyLoadingLayers() && $root.currentlyLoadingLayers().length">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.currentlyLoadingLayers">
        <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you are manpulating the underlying array of the `observableArray` bypassing the knockout subscriptions on the `observableArray` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knockout will notify subscribers when an items in an `observableArray` are added or removed, or if the entire collection is replaced. But only when done through the `observableArray` object and not by manipulating the underlying array directly.

So this will notify subscribers:

```
self.currentlyLoadingLayers.splice(i, 1)
```

This won't:

```
self.currentlyLoadingLayers().splice(i, 1)
```

And this will:

```
self.currentlyLoadingLayers([])
```

Please check the documentation for [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

I've added some comments in your code with some explanation:

```
self.layerLoadingFinished = function(layerName) {
    for (var i = self.currentlyLoadingLayers().length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (self.currentlyLoadingLayers()[i] === layerName) {
            //this line modifies the underlying array directly bypassing ko's notifiers
            //change this to self.currentlyLoadingLayers.splice(i, 1)
            //to notify subscribers after each item is removed
            self.currentlyLoadingLayers().splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    //this line uses self.currentlyLoadingLayers([]) which changes 
    //the underlying array through ko and will notify subscribers
    if (self.currentlyLoadingLayers().length === 0) self.currentlyLoadingLayers([]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now. Being new to knockoutjs (I inherited the project) I didn't appreciate the difference between `.splice` and `().splice`. I think the bit that confused me was that the notification from `.push` was clearing previous items that had been removed with `().splice` making it look like `().splice` was notifying subscribers.

Comment: @AndyNichols no problem buddy, glad I could help : )